Why virtual thread is not garbage collected when not reachable
I would like my virtual thread is garbage collected when blocking queue, which the thread consumes, is thrown away.
It should work: according to https://openjdk.org/jeps/444,

Unlike platform thread stacks, virtual thread stacks are not GC roots.
Thus the references they contain are not traversed in a stop-the-world
pause by garbage collectors, such as G1, that perform concurrent heap
scanning. This also means that if a virtual thread is blocked on,
e.g., BlockingQueue.take(), and no other thread can obtain a reference
to either the virtual thread or the queue, then the thread can be
garbage collected — which is fine, since the virtual thread can never
be interrupted or unblocked. Of course, the virtual thread will not be
garbage collected if it is running or if it is blocked and could ever
be unblocked.

See my code
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);
    Thread thread = fireVirtualConsumer(blockingQueue);
    blockingQueue = null;
    thread = null;
    System.out.println("Blocking queue is: " + blockingQueue + " thread is " + thread);
    // here I catch thread/heap dump
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
}

private static Thread fireVirtualConsumer(BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue) {
    return Thread.ofVirtual().start(() -> {
        try {
            for(;;) {
                blockingQueue.take();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Demo interrupted");
        }
    });
}

When I catch the heap dump, I see that the ArrayBlockingQueue is not candidate for GC
java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue 0x6059ac1a0 504 B
    arg$1 of Demo$$Lambda+0x00000200a1003200 0x6059acf40 520 B
        val$task of java.lang.VirtualThread$VThreadContinuation$1 0x6059c1c98 544 B
            target of java.lang.VirtualThread$VThreadContinuation 0x6059c1bf8 624 B
                cont of java.lang.VirtualThread 0x6059c1728 904 B
                    key of java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node 0x6059c2350 936 B
                        java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[16] 0x6059c2300 1,02 kB
                            table of java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap 0x6059bfaa8 1,08 kB
                                map of java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView 0x6059bfa90 1,1 kB
                                    VTHREADS of jdk.internal.vm.ThreadContainers$RootContainer$TrackingRootContainer, GC Root: Sticky class 0x6059bf9f0 1,22 kB

And VirtualThread also
java.lang.VirtualThread 0x60454dc40 904 B
    key of java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node 0x60454e798 936 B
        java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[16] 0x60454e748 1,02 kB
            table of java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap 0x60454bfa0 1,08 kB
                map of java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView 0x60454bf88 1,1 kB
                    VTHREADS of jdk.internal.vm.ThreadContainers$RootContainer$TrackingRootContainer, GC Root: Sticky class 0x60454bee8 1,22 kB

Virtual thread seems be blocked:

#30 "" virtual
java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.park(VirtualThread.java:582)
java.base/java.lang.System$2.parkVirtualThread(System.java:2643)
java.base/jdk.internal.misc.VirtualThreads.park(VirtualThreads.java:54)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:369)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:519)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3780)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3725)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1707)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:420)
Demo.lambda$fireVirtualConsumer$0(Demo.java:24)
java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309)

Demo.java:24 is blockingQueue.take();
What is wrong? Why virtual thread is visible from CG root when ArrayBlockingQueue is empty, not visible from main and VirtualThread is also not visible main?

Is it really blocked?

@aled, I added output from jcmd <PID>Thread.dump_to_file -format=txt

There is no guarantee that anything is ever garbage-collected.

@user207421 I do not comply that virtual thread and event queue are present in heap. I comply they are visible from GC Root "VTHREADS" and will be never collected and cause memory leak

I guess the reason here is that your queue is captured by the lambda, and it's assumed to be accessible

@Irremediable I replaced lambda by class implementing Runnable and result is the same

I also noted that virtual threads are not garbage collected, but until now I didn’t know that it was once intended otherwise. However, the JEP is not a specification, things can change until the final implementation. Unfortunately, there is no specification about the intended behavior.

@michaldo posted a question about this to one of the JDK development mail lists. Interesting discussion followed. The conclusion seem to be that it is not clear whether or not virtual treads should be garbage collected. Maybe this behaviour will change again in the future. (Do you agree with this summary, @michaldo?)

The problem is caused by JVM setting jdk.trackAllThreads, enabled by default. It blocks virtual thread from garbage collecting, until the thread is done.
It means the property breaks JEP 444
Workaround: java -Djdk.trackAllThreads=false
Update
This issue is reported as https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8336061
and  solved as mistake in documentation. JEP 444 is updated. Paragraph describing garbage collecting is removed.
Summary
Actual doctrine says that blocked VT are not GC'ed and it is expected behavior.
By default they are not collected because they are strongly referenced for tracking purpose. It means there in not "special" rule protecting blocked VT against GC. Tracking protects VT. If tracking is disabled, VT are not strongly referenced and are reclaimed by CG according to general rules.
Tracking flag in undocumented.
(In physics this phenomenon is called Observer effect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics))
It is possible to create VT hidden under Future:
Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor().submit(Runnable)
and  Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(Thread.ofVirtual().factory()).submit(Runnable)
If Executor and Future are GC'ed, blocked VT is also GC'ed. This behavior does not depend on jdk.trackAllThreads. It is undocumented as well

For reference: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8309406

Additional information to readers: Alan Bateman notes in this mail that jdk.trackAllThreads is an undocumented property. That implies that it might change behaviour or be removed in future releases.
